# What is the lowest fee one can pay to make a monero transaction?

Tags: transaction-fees

Is it possible to make a transaction without paying a fee or what is the lowest fee amount one can send with?

How long does it take to get your coins back if the network does not accept your transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [monero.how calculator](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5984/how-to-calculate-exact-monero-transaction-and) the lowest priority (1x) fee is currently about .00168 XMR assuming 1 input, 1 output and a ring size of 5

With a more common  1 input, and 2 outputs and a ring size of 5 the lowest fee is currently about .00312

With 2 input, and 2 outputs and a ring size of 5 thelowest fee is currently about .00336

Generally transactions that are not accepted by th network are [dropped from the txpool after 24 hours](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3335/145)

**EDIT:** As JollyMort stated in the comment below the min network relay fee is codified  based on the transaction size divided by the block size multiplied by the block reward and a set multiple:

```
((TX size)/(block size)) * (block reward) * 1.2%
```

Individual wallet clients are free to label the different fee priority levels however they like but the math remains the same. Monero.how chooses to refer to the 1x priority fee as "lowest" and the official GUI refers to the .25x priority fee as ["slow"](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/blob/e9b6c510f4bf552e946ae55ef12e081b99882eb3/components/StandardDropdown.qml#L200). The answer is still the same as defined in code.

Comment: But a 1x fee is the default priority fee, not the lowest. The GUI wallet includes the option "Slow (x0.25 fee)".

Comment: It's a matter of presenting. The min. fee is `(TX size)/(block size) * (block reward) * 1.2%` IIRC. We can call that 0.25x or 1x, depending what we use as reference. It's a network relay rule, so a miner could include 0-fee TX-es if he somehow receives them. He could mod his node and you could mod yours and if you're connected directly he could see and add your 0-fee TX. Other nodes wouldn't relay this though. If it's in a block, then it would be accepted.